# No sound in Minecraft

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Since the new update, my sound for Minecraft hasn't been working. I'm afraid that if I uninstall it then install it again then I'll have to pay again. Does anyone know what to do?

Comment: You don't have to pay twice for minecraft. I've lost count of how many times I've uninstalled/installed minecraft. So don't worry, go ahead, and delete your .minecraft folder (removing the launcher isn't going to do anything at all.

Comment: are the sounds enabled in the options menu?

Answer (score 5):

**No. you don't have to pay again for reinstalling**

If you are having no sound, first try this – hold F3 then press S while you are in Minecraft. This might work.

If that doesn't help, go on and reinstall minecraft. i'm 120% sure you don't have to pay again. You just need your account to download it again.

Answer (score 0):

The game can be downloaded for free on minecraft.net. You need to pay for an account, so once that account is setup, you can install/uninstall the game as many times as you like, and your account is still there.  You should be able to play on another computer (ie at a friend's house) with your account as well.

Think of it as buying the account instead of buying the game, but you can't play without an account.